# Can't get SSL set up with WordPress consistantly

Tags: wordpress, ssl, mixed-content

I need to get www.riversdown.com to be fully secure.

When I view the site in FF every page loads. When I view it in Chrome or Safari the homepage loads fine but all other pages do not, as it gives the mixed content error. Some pages load fine and some do not, but these pages see to change over time.

If I look at the source for the css file, for example, in FF I see:

```
<link rel='stylesheet' id='mine-css'  href='https://www.riversdown.com/wp-content/themes/riversdown/_/css/style.css?ver=all' type='text/css' media='all' />
```

But in the other two browsers I see:

```
<link rel='stylesheet' id='mine-css'  href='http://www.riversdown.com/wp-content/themes/riversdown/_/css/style.css?ver=all' type='text/css' media='all' />
```

It seems that any WP generated link (via get_template_directory_uri() or bloginfo('template_directory') isn't being forced to use https://

In Settings I have both WordPress and Site Address set to https://

I have tried to use the plugins: "SSL Insecure Content Fixer" & "Really Simple SSL", but they do not seem to help.

As I write this, the following pages are not working:
https://www.riversdown.com/why-choose-us/12-reasons-to-choose-us/

https://www.riversdown.com/learn-english/true-immersion/

https://www.riversdown.com/our-locations/rlc-sweden/stockholm-main-office/

Comment: All permalinks and image URL's work fine in the pages I'm having problems with, it just seems to be the URL's gernerated by php in the templates or plugins.

Comment: I have also tried add this the my .htaccess:
# START #
# Force HTTPS
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
# END #
But then the browsers can't open page at all, Something about too many redirects occurred.

Answer (score 0):

That sounds like you have the old version cached. Make sure you clear your cache in both browsers and check again.

Comment: clearing browser cache doesn't really help. The client is having issues and their customer, the SSL has been in place for about a month. But when I set it I used Firefox, which showed it working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Right, after trying various htaccess snippets I found on various threads, this is the one that finally worked for me without giving mixed content warnings or too many redirection errors

```
# BEGIN SSL REDIRECT
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{ENV:HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]

# BEGIN WordPress
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress + SSL REDIRECT
```